# Can't query properties with colon

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-spatial

I am new to neo4j, so my question may sound stupid to you but anyway.

I have OSM data set imported to neo4j graph db. So curretnly I am trying to query different stuff from db, like:

```
MATCH (a) WHERE has(a.addr:street) RETURN a.addr:street
```

and it fails with an sysntax error:

```
Type mismatch: expected Node but was Boolean, Number, String or Collection<Any> (line 1, column 23)
"MATCH (a) WHERE has(a.addr:street) RETURN a.addr:street"
                       ^
```

Which is strange, as the nodes has a lot of properties with colons(:).

Does anybody know how can I query such properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Neo4j! Characters like `:` or whitespace can introduce ambiguity in a query since they may be significant in the query language, which gives the parser hick ups. You can still use these characters by enclosing the expression in "backticks", i.e.

```
MATCH (a) WHERE has(a.`addr:street`) RETURN a.`addr:street`
```

You can see some other examples [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-expressions.html).

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I am seeing weird thing: this query is not working from new web UI shell (2.0). I am getting 'Invalid input ''': expected whitespace or an identifier (line 1, column 29)' error. But as for shell everything works properly.

Comment: You have to use backticks: [`\``], not single quote: [']. (Same character as is used on StackOverflow for posting short code snippets.)

Answer (score 0):

There are three parts of a cypher query:

START,MATCH AND RETURN.
So your query here will be ::

```
START a=node(1)
MATCH (a)-[:HAS]->(addr)-[:HAS]->(street)
RETURN street
```

Comment: Probably I explained bad. The problem is that nodes in db contains properties like (key=addr:street, value=Rennweg). So I cant query nodes with such property notations. If a.addr:street will be substituted to a.name - everything is ok.