# neo4j load csv when field name has a '.' in it

Tags: neo4j

I'm loading a tab delimited file using LOAD CSV where the fieldnames are on the first line of the file.  However a few of the field names have a '.' in and I can't get any of the ways mentioned in similar posts to work. ([Can't query properties with colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048882/cant-query-properties-with-colon)) for example.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/home/user/Desktop/file" AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'
MERGE (n:IP {addr: `line.id.orig_h` });
```

and my file has this in it:

```
> ts    uid id.orig_h   id.orig_p   id.resp_h   id.resp_p
1442775590.662028   CAYN7w2ejAV3Rji8X2  1.2.3.4 55819   8.8.8.8 53
1442775595.716739   C0AaEWYns8YwqC9Sg   1.2.3.4 55826   8.8.8.8 8192
1442775335.453432   C0AaEWYns8YwqC9Sg   1.2.3.4 55555   8.8.8.8 8192
```

The error is:
QueryExecutionKernelException: Cannot merge node using null property value for addr

If I use CREATE instead of MERGE it will create a node but the addr property is empty.

If I enclose the field name in backticks like a few posts mention to do, I get the following error:

QueryExecutionKernelException: line.id.orig_h not defined (line 2, column 20 (offset: 107))
"MERGE (n:IP {addr: `line.id.orig_h` })"

I'm using neo4j community v2.2.5.

If I get rid of the '.' in the field names the graph is created successfully.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: what if you bactick only the field name : ```{addr: line.`id.orig_h` }```

Answer (score 1):

Chris is right, backticks are your friend:

```
 {addr: line.`id.orig_h` }
```